# Single row with overflow Ellipsis with fixed content left and fixed content right

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a sidebar with Facett-Checkboxes.
The width of the sidebar can change and is not under my control. 
I want to have a checkbox, a description and the result count in one line for saving space.

The the count should be right aligned inside sidebar, the checkbox left. The description should take the remaining space with overflow: ellipsis for accessibility.

The solution is preferred with css only. If not possible also js could be used.

For exemple code see https://jsfiddle.net/z9d8qjsb/7/

html

```
<div class="sidebar_a">
<div class="row">
    <input id="ckb" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ckb">
      <span class="text">Description that can be verry long and should use ellipsis</span>
      <span class="count">(xxxx)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="ckb" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ckb">
    <span class="text">Short Desc.</span>
      <span class="count">(xxxx)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar_b">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="ckb" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ckb">
      <span class="text">Description that can be verry long and should use ellipsis</span>
      <span class="count">(xxxx)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="ckb" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ckb">
    <span class="text">Short Desc.</span>
      <span class="count">(xxxx)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.sidebar_a {
  width: 500px; 
  }

  .sidebar_b {
    width: 100px;
  }

  .sidebar_a, .sidebar_b {
    border: 2px solid black; /*only for illustration*/
  }

  .row {
    position: relative;
  }
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.count {
  position: absolute;
}
```

UPDATE: html updated for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidebar {
  // width: 200px; 
  border;
  2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.count {
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

#ckb {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin-top:6px;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="ckb" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ckb">
      <span class="text">Description that can be verry long and should use ellipsis</span>
      <span class="count">(xxxx)</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the width of the sidebar is not under my control. Unfortunately i cant't take this away.

Comment: The sidebar is part of a drupal template. Changing the template changes the width of the sidebar. But my code should look pretty on every width.

Comment: can not you overide slider width?

Comment: The sidebar is used by many modules. Forcing to use my custom width would break their layout.

Comment: you can use parent e id/class to this particular modul to customise witdth.

Comment: parent id/class is not known, since my content can be placed in different regions (sidebar_a, sidebar_b, header, ...). It should take maximum space within it's parent.

Comment: You can inspect in browser  and see for that particular code what is parent element is wrapping .

Comment: the parent div is dynamic. i see no possibility for referencing the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
.count {
  right: -5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I change the `right` properties in minus i think its work for you

Comment: by using minus width the count would by outside the box.

Comment: Then reduce `.text` class width like 50% or as you want

Comment: I want .text class use the maximum space available. The sidebar can range from 100px to 600px. The count can range from 1 to several millions.